# How do I test IPX connectivity between two computers?

Tags: networking

I want to play Starcraft with a friend, but something is wrong.

How do I test IPX connectivity between two computers?

Comment: What year have I landed in?

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using IPX? Starcraft supports TCP/IP. Make sure you have the latest patch.

Answer (score 0):

Have we just found the last person in the world who uses IPX?

Anyway, the link [here](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&source=hp&q=test+ipx+connectivity&btnG=Google+Search&meta=&aq=f&oq=test+ipx+connectivity&fp=f97642039f6cca8c) should help.

Comment: Interestingly, this question's listed third in those search results.  Not much out there, is there?

Comment: We still have a customer with the following setup (done before we took over the support): RHEL on one server, Netware on another running a legacy DOS app. Plus, a Windows 95 box whose sole purpose is to mount the Netware drives via IPX so that the RHEL box can back up the Netware server.